# Call to member function on NULL in Laravel PhP

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have the below error. The client model has a relationship with the appointments model. When I replace variable $client with their id (1), it successfully returns a collection of appointments. But with the variable it returns NULL. I am trying to loop through each client's appointment to work out the duration total. My error is that i can't retrieve appointments when using $client variable from previous for each loop.

FYI the foreach $clients as $client loop returns a collection of all clients.

> Call to a member function appointments() on null

public function autoGenerate(Request $request)   {

```
    $date1       =  $request->input('date_from');
    $date2       =  $request->input('date_to'); 
    $customer    = $request->input('customer_account');

    if(count($customer) > 0)
    {       
        $clients     = Customer::find($customer)->client()->get();

        foreach($clients as $client)
            { 
                $appointments = Client::find($clients)->appointments()->get();

                    foreach($appointments as $appointment)
                    {       
                        //other code            
                    }               
            }

        //other code


    }
    $invoices = Invoice::all();
    return redirect('invoice');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how your `$client` variable is built, but you should probably use

```
$appointments = Client::find($client)->appointments()->get();
```

Or

```
$appointments = Client::find($client->id)->appointments()->get();
```

> Note in my first example the usage of `$client` instead of `$clients`.

Comment: I had tried $clients and $client. Both returned same error. However your suggestion $client->id returns the first client's appointments only when I dd($appointments);
I would have expected all the appointments to be returned for each client?

Comment: You said that when you used the id of the client it worked, so the question is how to get the id of the client from the variable `$client`. I assumed it is `$client->id` but I don't know you structure.

Comment: Ok. I have run the whole process through and it works fine. dd(); seemed to only return either the first client or the last client depending on which side you placed it on the } closure of the foreach loop.  Thank you.

Comment: Great. Glad I could help!